# If ${a_n}\rightarrow\infty\Rightarrow\frac{a_n}{e^{a_n}}\rightarrow 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is driving me crazy. How to show that? Even though it looks intuitive, I cannot find a proper way to prove it. I tried to use the definition, to proof by absurdity, but still cannot. I do not unterstand what I am missing. Any hint?

Comment: What do you know about $e^x$? Say when compared to polynomials?

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{x}{e^x}$?

Comment: @Peanut That limit is 0, but how does that help? I

Comment: Try to consider $a_n = e^{ln(a_n) }$

Comment: Maybe use that $e^x \geq 1+x+x^2/2 \geq x^2/2$ for positive x, this inequality is still true if we replace x with $a_n$

Comment: @NajKamp that looks awesome. Like it.

Answer (score 4):

For other two methods given below, you have to assume that $f$ is differentiable. But if you use
$$ e^x>x^2 $$
for large $x$, you don't need this assumption. In fact
$$ 0\le \frac{a_n}{e^{a_n}}\le \frac{1}{a_n} $$
for large $n$. This gives
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{e^{a_n}}=0. $$

Comment: OK that looks good, thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

Although xpaul gave an excellent answer,

I wanted to post a reason why given that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$$

and

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$$ (where f is a function from the reals)

we can deduce that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = 0$$

The proof is from Theorem 2.4 here: [https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch2.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/m125a/intro_analysis_ch2.pdf)

'sequential characterization of the limit'

So applying it to this problem $f(x)$ would be $\frac{x}{e^x}$

I will just prove the forward direction for infinity here.

So we're given that:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$$

So given an $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a real number $R>0$ such that $x>R$ implies $|f(x)-0| < \epsilon$

We're also given that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \infty$$

which means that for every real number $M>0$, there is a natural number $N$ such that $n>N$ implies $a_n > M$. So we pick $M=R$. So we have an $n>N$ such that $a_n>R$

But that implies that if $n>N$ then:

$|f(a_n)-0| < \epsilon$

So given an $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an N such that $n>N$ implies $|f(a_n)-0|<\epsilon$

That proves that:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = 0$$

So we can use l'Hopital's rule here:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{e^x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{e^x} = 0$$

and deduce that given $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=\infty$$,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{a_n}{e^{a_n}} = 0$$

Comment: Thank you! This is a wonderful way to prove it. I can also see the relation between the limit of sequences and functions in that way.

Comment: @Filip98, you're welcome. I wasn't clear about this subtlety between functions and sequences until I tried to answer your question.